# calculate time in data processing into XML and CSV

Tags: c#, .net

I made a program (C#, .NET) that calculates time for XML and CSV export and please I have a question for improving my knowledge in programming. Do you think that I can improve the structure of the program? Or what do you think about code refactoring? Way of solve... Is it good? I uploaded the project to github.
Thanks for your comments.

```
                    t.SetupWriteStart(TestType.String); //that inicialize collection, stringreader, stringstringwriter
                    Time = CalculateTime(t.TestWriteString);
                    t.SetupWriteEnd(TestType.String); //delete this collection, close stringreader and writer
```

[Github link](https://github.com/Argellius/CalculateXMLCSV)

Comment: That's a very small piece of code you shared, we can't meaningfully review that. If you want the code on GitHub reviewed, please include the major parts of it in the question itself. We can't review code that's behind a link.